# How do I run a exe silently in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I made a script that executes an EXE, which changes fan speed of my laptop. But on boot I get annoying console popup, how do I make it go away?

vbscript:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "DellFanCmd", "ec-disable-nofanchg", "", "runas", 1
objShell.ShellExecute "DellFanCmd", "fan1-level1", "", "runas", 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [ShellExecute method](https://ss64.com/vb/shellexecute.html)

***Syntax***

```
.ShellExecute "application", "parameters", "dir", "verb", window
.ShellExecute 'some program.exe', '"some parameters with spaces"', , "runas", 1
```

***Key***

```
application   The file to execute (required)
parameters    Arguments for the executable
dir           Working directory
verb          The operation to execute (runas/open/edit/print)
window        View mode application window (normal=1, hide=0, 2=Min, 3=max, 4=restore, 5=current, 7=min/inactive, 10=default)
```

So your code can be written as below by changing `1` to `0`

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "DellFanCmd", "ec-disable-nofanchg", "", "runas", 0
objShell.ShellExecute "DellFanCmd", "fan1-level1", "", "runas", 0
```

Comment: Don’t use `Shell.Application` but this seems a useful option.